# What is wrong with my hotkey map?

Tags: linux, console

Gernally speaking, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f7</kbd> will switch from text mode into graphic mode.
And to input tty in graphic mode result in pts.

In my pc,<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> will switch from text mode into graphic mode,to input tty in graphic mode result in tty1.
[image]
What is wrong with my hotkey map?
Maybe some config file was messed up.
How to find it?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your hotkey map. Your distribution just starts the X server on the [virtual terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) number 1, instead of virtual terminal number 7 as other distributions do.

If you want to change that: The X server is usually started by the [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29). Different display managers have different configuration files. Eventually, the display manager executes the `X` binary with an option of `vt n`, where *n* is the virtual terminal number.

Comment: The move from vt7 to vt1 is close to a decade old, now.  [It was a big thing in the world of RedHat in 2008](https://lwn.net/Articles/305774/).